# Efficient way to remove duplicate slug from model in Django

Tags: django, django-models

In my `Exam` model, I used a `slug field` which is `not unique`. But now, I want to make it unique. So I added `Unique=True` constraint in my slug field.

Since there are many exam data in the database that contain same slug. This causes problem while migrating, so, I want to find an efficient way to find all duplicate slugs and make them unique.
Any suggestion and help will be appreciated.

Comment: Create a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/writing-migrations/#writing-database-migrations) first where you loop through all the duplicates and replace them (e.g. adding an integer at the end). Then create the migration where the field becomes unique. Then run both migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this reasonably efficiently by using an update to append a unique value - ie the PK - to the slug. For example:

```
from django.db.models import Value, F, CharField
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

duplicates = Exam,objects.values('slug').annotate(slug_count=Count('slug')).filter(slug_count__gt=1)
for dupe in duplicates:
    Exam.objects.filter(slug=dupe['slug']).annotate(
        new_slug=Concat('slug', Value('-'), 'id', output_field=CharField())
    ).update(slug=F('new_slug'))
```

As dirk suggests, this should be done in a separate data migration, *before* you make the slug unique.

Comment: `Exam.objects.value('slug').annotate(slug_count=Count('slug'))`   returns 
`[{'slug_count': 1, 'slug': u'exam-9'}, {'slug_count': 1, 'slug': u'test'}, {'slug_count': 1, 'slug': u'test'}, {'slug_count': 1, 'slug': u'exam7'}, {'slug_count': 1, 'slug': u'test'}]` and 
 this returns blank string `duplicates = Exam,objects.values('slug').annotate(slug_count=Count('slug')).filter(name_count__gt=1)`

Comment: Sorry, updated. You need to access the actual value via the `['slug']` key.

Comment: `Exam,objects.values('slug').annotate(slug_count=Count('slug')).filter(slug_count__gt=1)` this returns me a blank list.

Comment: Then you don't have any duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issue in the past, and this was my ***hacky*** way for solving it.

> unique should be set to False

Assuming the **models.py** below,

```
# models.py

from django.db import models
from .utils import unique_slug_generator


# Create your models here.

class ExamManager(models.Manager):
    def slug_it_out(self):
        exams = Exam.objects.all()
        for exam in exams:
            exam.slug = unique_slug_generator(exam)
            exam.save()
        return print('Slugged out')


class Exam(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120, blank=True, unique=False)

    objects = ExamManager()
```

I've created a function ***slug_it_out*** in the model manager class ***ExamManager*** that renames the slug based on another function i suggest you implement for generating slugs.

> To generate automatically when you create a new model object you can make use of pre_save or post_save signals

Next to your ***models.py*** create a ***utils.py*** and add the following.

```
# utils.py

from django.utils.text import slugify

def unique_slug_generator(instance, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(instance.title)
    new_slug = slug
    Klass = instance.__class__
    numb = 1
    while Klass.objects.filter(slug=new_slug).exists():
        new_slug = "{slug}-{num}".format(
            slug=slug,
            num=numb
        )
        numb += 1
    return new_slug

    # This assumes that the slug is generated from the exam title.
    # Appends an incrementing integer to duplicates
```

To run the function ***slug_it_out*** in the ExamManager class, simply go to the shell,

> python manage.py shell

Run the following;

```
# In the shell,
>>> from exams.models import Exam
>>> Exam.objects.slug_it_out()
```

You should see **Slugged out** printed on the screen. Feel free to edit the code to your needs.